# Ruby and Pry (or other debugging gem): How can I show the definition of a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, pry

I need to know how to check where the variable is - if not defined - then where it is assigned. Via Pry or similar gem (or Ruby standard library, that is - if possible)

Comment: Variables are not supposed to have a definition but just a simple assignment. If you want to check the definition of a method though, you can type "step" once your debugger has stopped on the line where the method is used.

Comment: To see the value of the variable, pry (and byebug which I often use) provides a console prompt where you can just type the variable and it will print the value.  To see the class of the variable, you can append `.class` after the variable name to print the class.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I need to know how to check where the variable is - if not defined - then where it is assigned, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the closest I can come up with right now to answer your question. Please check [pry-moves](https://github.com/garmoshka-mo/pry-moves)

You could use it to debug the start-up of the execution of your program and use `watch variable` (if you at least know the name of the variable) and look when it gets a value, there you would know in which step of the execution it is defined/declared.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will try.

Comment: Did it work for you? I tested it and it seems to do what you need. Don't forget to mark my answer in case you solved your doubt.

Comment: Dear svelandiag, I am still concerned with steps that precede this one in my login-scenario. I will come back to your answer when I am ready and of course I will, if it works out, check your answer as "accepted answer" :)